# TSQL attach db that is currently in use

Tags: sql-server

I have a shaprepoint system and I cannot attach the sharedservices_db

It is in use when I attempt to attach it.

I have stopped that web server associated with sharepoint data but no change in db is in use.

Any ideas?

Comment: In use by what? If you're attempting to *attach* it, clearly it isn't SQL Server that is using it.

Comment: What is telling you it is "in use"? SQL Server, Windows Explorer, something else? Is the database already attached to the current or another instance of SQL Server? You can only attach a database to a single instance at any time. This is one of the reasons I prefer backup/restore over detach/attach.

Comment: When I attempt to use the GUI to reattach the file.  This is the error I receive when I click on the add button.

Comment: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'F:\Databases\SUNFIRE_SharedServices_DB.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a select against sys.master_files for the file name that it's giving you grief about.  From there, you can see what database is using that file.

But of greater concern is that you're not trying to attach a database that has been attached.  You're trying to attach one that's still active.  Take five minutes and re-evaluate what you're doing before you have an accident.

Comment: I can see the db and log rows in sys.master_files.  But sp_helpdb SUNFIRE_SharedServices_DB says that teh db does not exist.

Comment: I found that the files "SUNFIRE_SharedServices_DB " were being used by SUNFIRE_SharedServices_Search_DB